# Internet Explorer is adding a space with round corner

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I have a div with a round corner (border-top-right-radius), and in IE11 is adding a white line, around 1px on the left.

If I leave the "border-top-right-radius" the line dissapears.
If I use the zoom it dissapears, I think that it is an approximation error.

[image]

Any idea?
Thanks

Code:

```
<li>
<a>Environment</a>
</li>
```

Look this with IE11...
http://jsfiddle.net/hkg4Z/

Comment: What do you mean by "if I use the zoom"?  What zoom?  The browser's zoom?  CSS' `zoom`?

Comment: without code we cannot help you.

Comment: Are you using `display: inline-block` on these elements?

Comment: with and without inline-block do the same.

Comment: It looks like an approximation error, if you resize the browser, you can see the line changing

Comment: This is a screenshot from browserstack, and I don't see this behaviour. http://i.imgur.com/VMikipW.png

Comment: @BlackCid see my updated answer for a workaround

Comment: @JanDrewniak if you zoom in on the screenshot, the issue is there

Comment: I think I have a solution, add the line you told me @Huangism but to the tag <a> instead of the <li>

Comment: I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve, but I am sure adding the border-radius somewhere else will solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround

http://jsfiddle.net/hkg4Z/2/

```
li{
    float: left;
    background:blue;
    height:34px;
    color:#fff;
    list-style:none;
    border-top-right-radius:8px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

I added a border

http://jsfiddle.net/hkg4Z/3/

border radius on the parent instead

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-top-right-radius:8px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: You aren't changing anything :-S

Comment: I have no space between the li, it does not work I thought it worked when I hit run on the fiddle but now it looks like the line is back

Comment: Look the red lines, the blue line cut the red line.

Comment: @BlackCid well of course since you give them a different colour lol what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @BlackCid your image has a white line on the left side of environment. If you only want the radius on the left-most and right-most of the entire nav, then put the border radius on the container instead of the li. If not then explain in detail what you are trying to achieve

Comment: from what I can see, adding even a 0.01px border on the li's seems to solve the issue.

Comment: 0.01px will round up to 1 px

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a known bug in I.E. 11 :(

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/a7808c7d-0178-4b10-b8b1-fbb06dd6ee28/ie-11-div-with-borderradius-bug?forum=iewebdevelopment

Answer (score 0):

If you have a solid background colour then you can remove the space by adding an inset box-shadow with the same colour.

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px blue;
```